# Combine multiple csv files (each file – 1 sample) into one dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataset

I am working on the [Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/4d260937c50d483e5a888c3d587180a3c53c4c962313c52829de7ec45c383b94) where each `.csv` file is one input or one sample (not `.csv` file with a row per sample) which I want to combine.

API Command to get dataset: `kaggle datasets download -d rebecacunha/mit-short-circuit-flux-and-current-signals`

I have tried combining all the files in one dataframe but that is not giving me the correct output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your question removing duplicated text and formatting. Please, try to formulate it as short as possible and format it nicely. It raises chances for the question to be answered significantly!

Answer (score 0):

When you need to merge several `.csv` files into one dataset you usually need one of pandas methods: please, refer to [merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html) article.